# Flexstore or JQuery for e-commerce site

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, e-commerce, shopping-cart, zend-server

Am currently evaluating the best RIA technologies to use for building a new e-commerce site.
Currently there are two options we are looking at.One is the [flexstore](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/inproduct/sdk/flexstore/flexstore.html) example where we intend to embed the intuitive shopping cart into our site or go full JQuery in providing the needed end user experience.We intend to use Zend as our server platform.

Our decision will take the following factors into consideration:

1. We should be able to progressively enhance the site with ease.
2. The technology adopted should be well documented and has an active following their respective forums.
3. Should give us minimal security headaches that are common with RIA technologies.

Am willing to here other factors that I should be considering in selecting one of the above mentioned RIA platforms.

Comment: Weird, you're comparing a e-commerce framework to a javascript util. lib ?

Comment: Simply wanted to know what is best technology stack to proceed with.Seems jQuery carried the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery because you want the largest user base you can get, and with devices like the iPhone, &etc, you guests may not be able to load the site and they won't understand why.